# How can I remember index and call it as the between function in GAMS?

Tags: optimization, gams-math

How can I code these two constriants in GAMS. It looks like the the constrains about `between function` that we need to remember index `t` value in the first constraint. Then, use this `t` value as the starting value in the second constraint for finding termination. Suppose `t /1*10/` .

[image]

Thanks

Comment: There would be a higher chance to get some help here, if you show the GAMS code you tried and explain based on that, where you have problems.

Comment: I think this could work with a loop...